# What is the meaning of rollover interrupt?

Tags: timer, embedded, interrupt, firmware

Does rollover mean resetting the timer to zero after reaching the highest limit?

Comment: In many contexts, yes. A rollover interrupt would be triggered when a counter (not necessarily a timer) rolls from its maximum value back to zero.

Comment: Without context it could mean number of things -  include a quote of the source of the term to provide context.  NO doubt the reference manual for the part you are using will make this clear.